# Why does Google Page-Speed say that elements need compressing, when they already are compressed?

Tags: .htaccess, compression, gzip, yslow, pagespeed

My page is compressed using the following in .htaccess

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
  mod_gzip_on Yes
  mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
  mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
  mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
  mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
  mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

Yslow says that the page and specifically the elements which Page-Speed is complaining about, are compressed and it gives the page an overall score of 90/100.

Why then, does Page-Speed say that

> Compressing the following resources with gzip could reduce their transfer size by 118.8KiB (70% reduction).

and it gives the page an overall score of 33/100?

Comment: Got an example of one of the resources, and the request/response headers for it?

Comment: Peter if you have a live example page that exhibits this problem, we could take a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

Your htaccess file only includes specific file extensions and mime types, presumably there are files being loaded which are compressible which are not specified
Either that or mod_gzip is not running on your server.